# Traversing member variables sequentially in a loop

Tags: c++

This is my implementation for traversing member variables in a class/struct sequentially in a loop and here's a typical example. My implementation looks ugly, looks like implemented with  brute force. How can it be improved or generalized. I want to advance through the variable like in a link-list's node->next or as in an array? Advice solicited. Thanks gurus in advance.

```
typedef struct {
    string name;
    string address;
    string phone;

    void set(const int idx, string str) {
        idx == 0 ? name = str : idx == 1 ? address = str : phone = str;
    }
    void print() const {
        std::cout << name << "-" << address << "-" << phone << '\n';
    }
} Person ;

int main()
{
    Person p;
    string str;
    stringstream ss{ "John London 9735048383" };

    int idx = 0;
    while (std::getline(ss, str, ' ')) {
        p.set(idx++,str); // Traversing the member variables.  The member variables will take turn to set their values in order.
    }
    p.print();

}
```

Edited: all member variables are of same type.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for "Reflection" which C++ doesn't support (yet?)

Comment: What you are trying to do is not easy in c++. If your members are dynamic you may be stuck with container of `std::variant`. If the members and their types are well known at compile time you can use a `std::tuple` as a sort of container for objects with different types.

Comment: Why would you want users of the class to care about which order its members are stored in?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: std::variance and std::tuple sound like a good idea.

Comment: @molbdnilo: In above example I have to split the stream into substrings sequentially. idk a better way.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Could you please give example with tuple ( for the given code) as I don't have c++17 to use std::variance

Comment: For example in the above example you could use a `std::tuple<std::string, std::string, std::string> members;`. Then `std::get<0>(members)` would replace`name`, `std::get<1>(members)` would replace `address` and `std::get<2>(members)` would replace `phone`. Though keep in mind that iterating over a `tuple` is not easy (you can just loop over it, each member has it's own type) and the `std::get<X>` index can't be runtime variables (you can't use `std::get<idx>(members)` for example). You need to use template meta-programming which can be a complex topic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Seems like perfect answer to me.

Comment: @ark1974 What's wrong with `ss >> p.name >> p.address >> p.phone;`?

Comment: @ark1974 No, `i` needs to be a compile time constant. The only time you could see `i` as a variable is if `i` was a template argument in a template meta-programming context or the result of a `constexpr` expression. Even then the term "variable" is a stretch.

Comment: @molbdnilo: with whitespace delimiter allow that?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks for your time. That looks still difficult for this trivial task

Comment: Oops these down votes gonna block me from asking further questions but the problem is genuine.

Comment: if you have that many members that you want to iterate them, then maybe better consider to have a single `std::vector<string>` as member, or a `std::map<string,string>` if you want them "named"

Comment: @user463035818: Wow seems like the solution to me. So std::array should also work. Can you post this as answer so that I can close this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using macros, you can also use pointer-to-members. Note that in C++ you don't have to `typedef struct`

```
struct Person {
    std::string name;
    std::string address;
    std::string phone;

    void print() const {
        std::cout << name << "-" << address << "-" << phone << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    Person p;
    std::string str;
    std::stringstream ss{ "John London 9735048383" };
    std::vector<std::string(Person::*)> members = { &Person::name, &Person::address, &Person::phone };

    for (auto it = members.begin(); std::getline(ss, str, ' ') && it != members.end(); ++it) {
        std::invoke(*it, p) = str;
        // Traversing the member variables.  The member variables will take turn to set their values in order.
    }
    p.print();
}
```

You can make the `invoke` slightly more palatable, providing you don't care about stopping on stream errors.

```
for (auto member : members)
{
    std::getline(ss, invoke(member, p), ' ');
}
```

Comment: @ark1974 you can also move that into a getPerson function (a.k.a. `operator >>`) [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e2314ac6b75e8ef)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want have something that can be generalized and you are willing to resort to macros, you can use [higher order macros](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2012/01/24/higher-order-macros-in-c/) for this. In your case, you would first add a macro that declares all the fields of your struct and their indices:

```
#define FOREACH_FIELD(OP)                       \
  OP(0, name)                                   \
  OP(1, address)                                \
  OP(2, phone)
```

Then, you would use this macro to implement your `Person` struct:

```
struct Person {
#define DECLARE_VAR(index, name) std::string name;
  FOREACH_FIELD(DECLARE_VAR)
#undef DECLARE_VAR

  void setField(int i, const std::string& value) {
    switch (i) {
#define SET_FIELD(index, name) case index: name = value; break;
    FOREACH_FIELD(SET_FIELD)
#undef SET_FIELD
      };
  }

  void print() {
#define PRINT_FIELD(index, name) \
    std::cout << #name << ": '" << name << "'" << std::endl;
    FOREACH_FIELD(PRINT_FIELD)
#undef PRINT_FIELD
  }
};
```

It looks ugly, and I would advice you to really think it through before adopting the above technique. Macros, in general, are avoided in C++. It makes your code harder to read, but if you have lots fields, well, you could use it. It *could* make your code more maintainable. After all, to add a new field, you only have to update the `FOREACH_MACRO`.

*Use this technique carefully.*

Comment: Thanks for your time. Should take me time to digest this.

Comment: @ark1974 This is just *one* possible approach. I would advice you to look at other answers too before deciding how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

std::array seemed to work for me as advised by [user463035818](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117728/user463035818) and this seems to be the simplest solution so far. std::map will have additional advantage to go alongside an alias name I guess.

```
typedef struct {
    std::array<string, 3> data;

    void print() const {
        std::cout << data[0] << "-" << data[1] << "-" << data[2] << '\n';
    }
} Person ;

int main()
{
    Person p;
    string str;
    stringstream ss{ "John London 9735048383" };

    int idx = 0;
    while (std::getline(ss, str, ' ')) {
        p.data[idx++] = str; 
    }
    p.print();

}
```